# Magento non www to www

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

I am pulling my hair out here.

I have created a landing page which is http://www.pps-supplements.com/samples

it works and you can access it fine - no problems.

If you type in the address bar:

pps-supplements.com/samples

it takes you to the home page which is not good and causing me to have a headache.

My website is working well for non www to www on home page and categories but not on cms pages.

I have read a few posts on here and tried their solutions which is to edit the htaccess file but it hasn't fixed it.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this issue??

Pretty please!

Comment: Is the Base URL in System>Config>Web set to WWW or no WWW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this in your .htaccess file....

Be sure to add it above any other rewrite rules or conditions you may already have in your htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.pps-supplements\.com [NC]
 Rewriterule (.*) http://www.pps-supplements.com/$1 [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect any domain that is not www.pps-supplements.com to the version with www's

Also very handy for using when pointing multiple domains at a site.

Also, be sure that the webserver is set-up to receive the non www version, as in that it is listening for that version, as well as for the version with www's.

Comment: Hi,Thank for your reply. I added it and tried it on safari and it seemed to work. I cleared my cache on chrome and it still took me to the home page when i typed in pps-supplements.com/samples any ideas? I have uploaded my htaccess as a txt now so that you can see what I already have - any ideas how to tweak this to get it working? http://www.pps-supplements.com/htaccess.txt I'm pretty sure that the server and the rest of the site is already work for non www. If you go to pps-supplements.com it will take you to www but none of the page, or categories in fact are working. HELP!!

Comment: For anyone else, I managed to get this solution to work by placing the RewriteCont and the RewriteRule lines above 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l'

Comment: Sorry for not getting back, yes I should have highlighted that this does need to be the first rewrite rule in your htaccess file. Updated

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking at the accepted answer and running into issues with it not working you may have other Rewrites in place that need to be stopped from executing.

You can stop further execution by including the "L" param.

Example:

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
Rewriterule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to redirect from **example.com/category/** to **www.example.com/category/**

and I found solutions:

turn off Auto-redirect to Base URL in backend
and use this code in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Magento Multistore-Setups:

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
Rewriterule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```